# Python Argparse: Use an empty flag

Tags: python, command-line, args

I'm trying to write a python script using `argparse` which sets a value to `True` if `-d` has been set.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
parser.add_argument("-d", "--dynamic", required=False)

dynamic = False
if args.dynamic is not None:
  dynamic = True
```

I get the following error:

> usage: psd.py [-h] -f FILE [-d DYNAMIC] psd.py: error: argument
>   -d/--dynamic: expected one argument

How do I set the flag to expect 0 arguments?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259001/python-argparse-command-line-flags-without-arguments

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the *action*:

```
parser.add_argument("-d", "--dynamic", action='store_true')
```

You may drop the "required" kwarg.

Comment: When I do this I don't get the error but dynamic is always equal to True even when I don't set the flag.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride: It sounds like you're still doing the `if args.dynamic is not None: ...` thing. If so, stop doing that. `store_true` makes the argument default to `False`, not `None`, if not provided.

Comment: ah nvm I see how this should be done args.dynamic will be True or False but always exist